# Gulp does not copy files after clean

Tags: javascript, gulp

I tried the following code to clean the `prod` folder before copying files from `scripts` to it;

```
gulp.task('clean', async function () {
    del(['prod/*']);
});

gulp.task('minify', gulp.series('clean'), function (done) {
    gulp.src('scripts/*.js')
        .pipe(size())
        .pipe(minify(require('./minify.conf.js')))
        .pipe(size())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('prod'));

    done();
});

gulp@4.0.2
```

but after executing the above script, I got an empty prod folder (`scripts` is not empty), I am wondering how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In gulp@4 or higher, the `task` method gets two arguments:

```js
/**
 * Register the task by the taskName.
 * @param taskName - Task name.
 * @param fn - Task function.
 */
task(taskName: string, fn: Undertaker.TaskFunction): void;
```

So your code should be:

```
gulp.task('minify', gulp.series('clean', function (done) {})
```